# How do I set the isolation level for SELECT statement?

Tags: postgresql, select, isolation-level, snapshot-isolation, postgresql-9.5

Using PostgreSQL 9.5 I would like to make sure that when I run a `SELECT` statement I get consistent results, i.e. if the table is modified while the `SELECT` is running, I want to get the state that was valid when the `SELECT` started.

Basically, it's like: Take a snapshot of a table, and don't allow updates to the table while the snapshot is being taken, and then deliver the snapshot, while updates are allowed again.

If I understood isolation levels correctly, `REPEATABLE READ` is what I'm looking for, isn't it?

Now my question is: How can I run a `SELECT` with `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level? Or am I missing something, and my approach is wrong? How would I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to get statement level consistency

A query *always* sees a consistent state of the database regardless of the isolation level you use.

[Quote from the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-intro.html)

> This means that each SQL statement sees a snapshot of data (a database version) as it was some time ago, regardless of the current state of the underlying data.

See the chapter about [Multi Version Concurrency Control](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-intro.html) in the manual

Comment: Okay, this is great news (as, in MongoDB this is different AFAIK).

Comment: Well the NoSQL databases specifically give up on transactions, consistency and transaction isolation for performance (and scalability) reasons.

Answer (score 4):

[Read committed](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html) (especially section 13.2.1) is the default read level in PostgreSQL.

This read level will give you a snapshot of what has been committed before your transaction starts. It will allow other transactions to read and write to your table, you just won't be able to see any writes made after the start of your transaction.

> Does this only apply to `SELECT`s run in the context of a transaction, or also to `SELECT`s that are run alone, without an explicit transaction around them (i.e., just a single `SELECT` statement, e.g. manually entered to the REPL)?

Again from the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-transactions.html):

> PostgreSQL actually treats every SQL statement as being executed within 
>   transaction. If you do not issue a `BEGIN` command, then each individual 
>   statement has an implicit `BEGIN` and (if successful) `COMMIT` wrapped 
>   around it. A group of statements surrounded by `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` is 
>   sometimes called a transaction block.

So, individual `SELECTs` (one after the other) **may** see different contexts. There will be a difference **if** another user has modified your tables in the meantime.

However (and this should clarify) in a query with *subselects* - the individual subqueries will be consistent i.e. see the same context.

Comment: One last question on this: If I want to run two `SELECT`s, one after the other, and I want to make sure that both definitely see the same data, is it enough to simply wrap them within `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`?

Comment: @GoloRoden not necessarily - if some other transaction commits before the second `SELECT` starts, the two may see different data.  In this case, you might need `REPEATABLE READ`.