# Phantom read during single statement execution in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, transaction, isolation-level

I wonder could there ever be a concurrent situation when phantom read occurs during single SQL statement execution?

Given: `tx_test` is a table with 3 rows and `id` column is primary key, `value` is some text payload. Tables `one_row_table1`, `one_row_table2`, `one_row_table3` all have 1 row *at start* of transaction. Consider SQL statement executed in `READ COMMITTED` transaction:

```
BEGIN;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED ;
WITH cte1 AS (
    UPDATE tx_test
        SET value = 'updated'
        WHERE id = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM one_row_table1)
        RETURNING id),
     cte2 AS (
         UPDATE tx_test
             SET value = 'updated'
             WHERE id = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM one_row_table1)
                                         /* what if one_row_table2 is used here? */
             RETURNING id),
     cte3 AS (
         UPDATE tx_test
             SET value = 'updated'
             WHERE id = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM one_row_table1)
                                         /* what if one_row_table3 is used here? */
             RETURNING id)
SELECT * FROM cte1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM cte2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM cte3;
COMMIT;
```

Could there be a case when the statement above updates more then 1 record?

In my experiments with similar situation but with 3 different statements inside one transaction I was easily able to get 2 rows updated. Of course it is true only when isolation level is lower than `SERIALIZABLE`.

```
BEGIN;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
-- 1
UPDATE tx_test
SET value = 'updated'
WHERE id = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM one_row_table1);
-- 2
-- Another transaction inserts into one_row_table1
UPDATE tx_test
SET value = 'updated'
WHERE id = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM one_row_table1);
-- 3
UPDATE tx_test
SET value = 'updated'
WHERE id = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM one_row_table1);
COMMIT;
```

From similar question [How do I set the isolation level for SELECT statement?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128269/how-do-i-set-the-isolation-level-for-select-statement) I know that

> ... This means that each SQL statement sees a snapshot of data (a database
> version) as it was some time ago, regardless of the current state of
> the underlying data. This prevents statements from viewing inconsistent data produced by concurrent transactions performing updates on the same data rows, providing transaction isolation for each database session. ...

Can I interpret this as PostgreSQL always provides `SERIALIZABLE` level of transaction isolation per statement? Or what kind of isolation?

Comment: If you try to update the same row twice in a single statement, you will get an error.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Data-modifying CTEs are apparently not considered the "same statement" and don't trigger an error. `UPDATE t SET a=1, a=1 ...` is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, phantom reads can occur in a single statement at `READ COMMITTED`. The easy way to trigger it is with table joins. We had a question here in October where a [join in `UPDATE` was disrupted by a concurrent update](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/318088/concurrent-update-on-two-different-tables-fail), and another referencing [anomalies during `LEFT JOIN`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/312261/inconsistent-data-when-combining-left-join-with-select-for-update).

These anomalies are detected or prevented at the `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level.

How your example causes 2 updates (which only fires the first update in the normal case):

1. In another session (B), lock the rows of `tx_test`:

   ```
   BEGIN;
   SELECT * FROM tx_test FOR UPDATE;
   ```
2. Execute the example query in session A. It will block on the first CTE.
3. While the example is blocked, add a row to `one_row_table1` in session B and commit the transaction:

   ```
   INSERT INTO one_row_table1 (data) VALUES (999);
   COMMIT;
   ```
4. The update will fire twice, first with `id=1` and second with `id=2`. The third will not fire to update `id=2` again.

At `REPEATABLE READ`, the insert into `one_row_table1` is not visible, and only one `UPDATE` fires.